# What's the fastest way to get content of multiple xls files?

Tags: java, php, xls

I have a set of 1200 xls files of which I need to create a csv-file containing

- The value of Cell A1 (if A1 is empty, take B1)
- The value of Cell A2 (if A2 is empty, take B2)
- The filename
- ID of String of Cell A2 (just a counter variable that is not incremented if the value of A1 has already been found, could be calculated afterwards)

The files are all Excel 97 files with a size between 25 and 500 KB.

While I know that it can be done in VBA, I assume it's way to slow. I know that it could be done in php (somehow) or Java. I don't know if the Win7 Batch or Mac OS X Terminal could help me. Any other ideas? I'm looking for the fastest way to solve this problem.

Comment: What have you tried? The fastest way is to probably try a couple things, and see which is fastest. If you "know" it could be done in PHP or Java, then why not give it a whirl?

Comment: @rmlan I have not yet tried anything. I didn't want to run into problems e.g. seeing that it just takes to long and then start right again from the beginning, having wasted much time. I am standing at a crossing and want to do the right decision before starting to walk...
I'm giving python a try, though never worked with it.
Knowing that it could be done just meant that I read that there are libraries that can do xls file handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [POI](http://poi.apache.org/) lib to read XLS files in Java but it is hard to grasp in you do not have enough Java experience. (the problem is that it sometimes encouters a problem and just cannot handle some XLS files for no particular reason)

Another stuff is PYTHON's [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) which is much easier.

What you choose depends on you. If you are in a hurry **xlrd** would be better.

Comment: Thanks. Never worked with python before but it did a pretty good job. Fast & easy.